# Flask routing - 404 error

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am trying to create a simple route in my Flask server where just visiting the URL would download a file. Here is my Flask code:

```
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/')

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path=UPLOAD_FOLDER)
Bootstrap(app)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.debug = False
app.secret_key = 'notverysecret'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    ...
    return render_template('index.html', request="POST", pitches=pitches)

@app.route('/mxl/')
def mxl():
  return app.send_static_file(UPLOAD_FOLDER + 'piece.mxl')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

However, when I visit `localhost:5000/mxl/` or `localhost:500/mxl`, I get a "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." error. In my command line I see:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 02:27:00] "GET /mxl/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Why is that happening?

When I run `app.url_map` I get the following output:

```
Map([<Rule '/mxl/' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> mxl>,
 <Rule '/' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> index>,
 <Rule '/home/myusername/guitartab/guitartab/static//bootstrap/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> bootstrap.static>,
 <Rule '/home/myusername/guitartab/guitartab/static//<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>])
```

Comment: I am no expert in Flask. However, I tried the approach in this website http://code.runnable.com/UiIdhKohv5JQAAB6/how-to-download-a-file-generated-on-the-fly-in-flask-for-python and it did work. I am assuming you want to allow user to download something once he/she clicks on a button. Basically you need make_response method to allow your user to do that. Another probable useful link https://matthewmoisen.com/blog/how-to-download-a-csv-file-in-flask/

Comment: Before, `app.run()`, do a: `print(app.url_map)` and edit your question to include the output.

Comment: I want the browser to automatically download the file like it does for this link: https://api.flat.io/v2/scores/56ae21579a127715a02901a6/revisions/last/mxl

Comment: @SuperSaiyan see updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that Flask has a parameter `static_folder`, which defaults to the 'static' folder in the root path of the application. And refer to doc to know [send_static_file(filename)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.send_static_file).

Just change your code to:

```
@app.route('/mxl/')
def mxl():
  return app.send_static_file('piece.mxl')
```

Or use [send_from_directory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory) if you want include the path:

```
from flask import send_from_directory
@app.route('/mxl/')
def mxl():
    print("test")
    #return app.send_static_file('piece.mxl')    
    return send_from_directory(UPLOAD_FOLDER,'piece.mxl')
```

it will download the file `piece.mxl` when you browse `http://127.0.0.1:5000/mxl/`

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to determine the downloaded file name? Right now it is just "mxl" without a file extension. Also I get a message from my browser "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://localhost:5000/mxl".". Why is that?

Comment: Fixed it with `send_from_directory(UPLOAD_FOLDER, 'piece.mxl', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='piece.mxl')`